# Representing binary relation in java

Tags: java

One famous programmer said "why anybody need DB, just give me hash table!". I have list of grammar symbols together with their frequencies. One way it's a map: symbol#->frequency. The other way its a [binary] relation. Problem: get top 5 symbols by frequency.

More general question. I'm aware of [binary] relation algebra slowly making inroad into CS theory. Is there java library supporting relations?

Comment: Like `java.lang.TreeSet implements java.lang.SortedSet`?

Comment: Looks like was is James Gosling, and the actual quote is `“I've never got it when it comes to SQL databases. It's like, why? Just give me a hash table and a sh*tload of RAM and I'm happy.”`

Comment: I use TreeSet symbol#->frequency right now, and still it seems to me that writing top 5 would take more than one minute. I assume that having converse relation (frequency, symbbol#) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<Entry<String, Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<...>();
 for (Entry<String, Integer> e : myMap.entrySet())
       myList.add(e);

 Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>(){

    int compare(Entry a, Entry b){
       // compare b to a to get reverse order
       return new Integer(b.getValue()).compareTo(new Integer(a.getValue());
    }
 });

 List<Entry<String, Integer>> top5 = myList.sublist(0, 5);
```

More efficient:

```
 TreeSet<Entry<String, Integer>> myTree = new TreeSet<...>(
    new  Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>(){

      int compare(Entry a, Entry b){
         // compare b to a to get reverse order
         return new Integer(b.getValue()).compareTo(new Integer(a.getValue());
      }
    });
 for (Entry<String, Integer> e : myMap.entrySet())
       myList.add(e);

 List<Entry<String, Integer>> top5 = new ArrayList<>();
 int i=0;
 for (Entry<String, Integer> e : myTree) {
     top5.add(e);
     if (i++ == 4) break;
 }
```

Comment: After looking at this, I think using a `TreeSet` instead of a `List` with the provided `Comparator` would probably be more efficient.

Comment: Do you mean reusing the input symbol->frequency map, or creating new one?

Comment: I was thinking new one because not sure how you are using the existing `Map`. In the above code, replace the `List myList` with a `TreeSet` and keep the `add` loop. Then there is no need to do the `sort`. You will just need to then iterate over the set to get the first 5 elements. Tree insertion should be more efficient than list sort.

Comment: Oops, I was silly: sure TreeSet is differnent from TreeMap by virtue of being unary (not binary) relation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general algorithm, assuming you already have a completed symbol HashTable

1. Make 2 arrays:

   - freq[5] // Use this to save the frequency counts for the 5 most frequent seen so far
   - word[5] // Use this to save the words that correspond to the above array, seen so far
2. Use an iterator to traverse your HashTable or Map:

   - Compare the current symbol's frequency against the ones in freq[5] in sequential order.
   - If the current symbol has a higher frequency than any entry in the array pairing above, shift that entry and all entries below it one position (i.e. the 5th position gets kicked out)
   - Add the current symbol / frequency pair to the newly vacated position
   - Otherwise, ignore.

Analysis:

- You make at most 5 comparisons (constant time) against the arrays with each symbol seen in the HashTable, so this is O(n)
- Each time you have to shift the entries in the array down, it is also constant time. Assuming you do a shift every time, this is still O(n)

Space: O(1) to store the arrays

Runtime: O(n) to iterate through all the symbols

Comment: Wouldn't using a `List<Entry<String, Integer>>` be better than two arrays?

Comment: @JohnB Indeed it would. I am rusty with Java so I opted for a general description to avoid syntax blunders. Thanks for the refresher in your solution!

Answer (score 0):

With `TreeSet` it should be easy:

```
int i = 0;
for(Symbol s: symbolTree.descendingSet()) {
    i++;
    if(i > 5) break; // or probably return
    whatever(s);
}
```

Comment: Is the `Symbol` a mutable object that contains and is ordered based on its frequency? That seems odd behavior for a `Symbol` class. Maybe a `SymbolFrequency`. How do you update the frequency of each element? Are you maintaining a `List` and you have to iterate to find the appropriate one? Or do you have a `Map<String, Symbol>` where the symbol is both the key and in the value?

Comment: `SymbolFrequency` is probably better name. I thought that frequencies are not changing while the program is running. `Map<Symbol, SymbolFrequency>` might be necessary for other operations. `List` won't be useful, I could just as well iterate over frequency set.